# pom.xml namespace necessary?

Tags: maven, pom.xml

Is there any need or usage for the namespace declarations in pom.xml's project tag?

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" ...
```

We have a tool that parses pom.xmls but it fails for pom.xmls containing a namespace declaration.

Answer (score 3):

All documentation for Maven tells you to use the namespace, and implies that it is required. For example, [the POM reference](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Quick_Overview) shows:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
```

However, the [`MavenXpp3Reader`](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.2.3/maven-model/apidocs/org/apache/maven/model/io/xpp3/MavenXpp3Reader.html) class that Maven uses to read the `pom.xml` files [doesn't check the namespace at all](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.maven/maven-model/2.0.9/org/apache/maven/model/io/xpp3/MavenXpp3Reader.java#1994). Any value (or even no value) won't prevent Maven from parsing the pom. (And even [correct use of namespaces can cause Maven to fail to parse](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-2715).)

However, just as you've got a tool that fails to parse valid poms, there are other tools out there which reimplement pom parsing and require the namespace declaration. Producing poms without could cause interoperability problems down the line.

In summary; you'll get away with it if you're building with Maven, but fixing the bug in your code would by far be preferable.

Comment: You wrote "there are other tools out there which reimplement pom parsing and require the namespace declaration".  Do you have concrete examples of such tools?

Comment: Good question; I don't recall specific examples, but then I've always had the declaration in my poms. I've written internal code that relies on it, but you may not consider that valid. A GitHub search for [`"http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" -extension:.xml`](https://github.com/search?q=%22http%3A%2F%2Fmaven.apache.org%2FPOM%2F4.0.0%22+-extension%3A.xml&type=Code)  may lead to some more context.

Comment: Yes, it's probably safest to have this declaration.  But then again, I hate XML verbosity so much that I am intentionally omitting it from my POMs until I run into some tool that actually requires it.  Really I'm only using a small set of tools (Visual Studio Code, Eclipse Java compiler, Maven) and so far everything is working fine without the declaration.

Answer (score 2):

In general it's a good style to add namespace information to your xml file. So it is good style to add those information to your pom file which can be helpful in particular if you are in tools like Eclipse etc. Furthermore you can validate your xml file against the XSD which is given there as well.

Apart from that if your tool has problems with such namespaces it's not a good tool cause it should handle namespace definitions correctly.

If you like to read pom file it shouldn't be a problem to implement that which correctly handles namespaces etc.

The following lines are needed to read the pom file:

```java
MavenXpp3Reader mavenReader = new MavenXpp3Reader();
Model pom = mavenReader.read(new FileReader(pomFile));
```

Comment: "Good style" is no answer to my question. Eclipse offers auto completion and validation without a namespace in the pom.xml

I do know the tool is not working very well while failing on declared namespaces.

MavenXpp3Reader is great to read pom.xmls but the MavenXpp3Writer is no appropriate solution for manipulating writing pom.xmls

The fastest and safest solution for us is to rip the few namespaces from off the pom.xmls but I wanted to if there is any usage for them.

Comment: I would suggest to take a look into versions maven plugin which exactly does things you would like to do.